# When do two limits commute?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $\{t_{n}\}$ is a sequence of zeros for a real valued function $f.\ (i.e. f(t_{n})=0,  \forall n$). Suppose that $t_{n}\rightarrow t_{0}$ and $f\in C^{2}(R)$. I want to find $f'(t_{0})$. I have tried the following:
Since $f'$ is cont. then I have
$$
f'(t_{0})=\lim_{n \to \infty} f'(t_{n})\\
=\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{t\rightarrow t_{n}}\frac{f(t)-f(t_{n})}{t-t_{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{t\rightarrow t_{n}}\frac{f(t)}{t-t_{n}}\\
=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_{n}}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(t)}{t-t_{n}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow t_{n}}\frac{f(t)}{t-t_{0}}=\frac{f(t_{n})}{t_{n}-t_{0}}=0.
$$

My question:

In the above computation I have used a commutation of the two limits. Is it possible?

Comment: Take $f(x)=x$, and $t_n =0$, then clearly $f'(t_0) = 1 \neq 0$, so the result cannot hold.

Comment: Consider $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{m}{n}$, which is $\infty$ or $0$ depending on which order you take the limits in.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The mean value theorem implies $f'(s_n) = 0 $ for a sequence $s_n\to t_0.$